# Scrapy 400 error only when crawling and not when using the Scrapy shell

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am receiving a 400 HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed error when using the Scrapy Crawl function to scrape BBC News article URLs from https://www.bbc.com/news/topics/c3np65e0jq4t. I am using the below code and command to initiate the scarping.

```
class bbc_url_spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'bbc_url_spider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/topics/c3np65e0jq4ts'
                ]
    user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1207.1 Safari/537.1"

    def parse(self, response):

        for url in set(response.css('a.ssrcss-1j8v9o5-PromoLink.e1f5wbog0::attr(href)').getall()):
            yield{
                'url': url
            }

        next_button = response.xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"e1b2sq420")]')[-1]
        next_page_link = next_button.css('a::attr(href)').get()

        if next_page_link is not None:
           yield response.follow('https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/topics/c3np65e0jq4t' + next_page_link, callback=self.parse)
```

```
scrapy crawl bbc_url_spider -O bbc_urls.json
```

Which returns this log.

[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GhBo.png)

However when using the Scrapy shell I am able to access the exact same webpage using a simple fetch.

[shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRbN8.png)

Not sure why this is happening. I have tried using different user agents and middleware but nothing seems to work. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Status code in  `400` and `500` range are errors and thus Scrapy ignores these by design.

If you have a specific case where you want to still call the callback methods such as `parse` for these status codes, you can do so by adding this in your Spider class:

```
    handle_httpstatus_list = [400, 404]  # note it's a list
```

In most cases, `400` would be an error. If you want, you can use `errback` to handle these errors. See [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-errbacks) for details.